# Set adapter for listview in fragment instead of activity

Tags: java, android, fragment, adapter

**Hello!**

I have tried to add a listview in a fragment but it doesn´t accept getApplicationContext:

```java
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
```

*and this:*

```java
Toast.makeText(Todo.this, "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

How do I make it work for fragment instead of activity?

**Code:**

```java
public class Todo extends Fragment {


    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    ListView listView;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public Todo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo, container, false);


        editText = editText.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = button.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        listView = listView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String YeniVeri = editText.getText() .toString();
                arrayList.add(YeniVeri);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Todo.this, "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider [accepting someone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `requireActivity()` or `container.context` in onCreatView. So you can also access "contex" via container.
Exp(Kotlin):

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   var mContext:Context? = container.context
```

Comment: Thanks! requireActivity seems to work but I don´t understand why the toast doesn´t. I don´t use Kotlin.  Toast.makeText(Todo.this, "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: for java  you can use "parent.getContext() " for Toast. Exp Toast.makeText(parent.getContext,..        or Toast.makeText(requireContext() ,, or Toast.makeText(requireActivity() ... what exactly do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

use requireActivity() instead of getApplicationContext and "ActivityName.this"

Comment: Thanks! requireActivity seems to work but I don´t understand why the toast doesn´t.  Toast.makeText(Todo.this, "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

shall work

Comment: you can as well use getActivity().getApplicationContext()
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();